# Compare for a specific string containing a substring of ranging numbers

Tags: python, regex, string, string-matching

How may I compare for a specific string containing a substring of ranging numbers in python?

Example: I have the following strings `"t (1)"`, `"t (2)"` and `"t (3)"`. They're all `"t (*)"` where `*` is always a number. In my usecase, it will always be `"t "` followed by a bracketed number.

I'm not sure how to essentially do:

`if (string == "t (*)"):`

where `*` is the range of numbers.

I googled variations of string comparison methods in python, but I don't know what's the right search term to use. I assume it involves regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is using regex.

```
import re

s = "t (99)"
match = re.search(r't \(\d+\)', s)
if match:
  # found the string
else:
  # did not find the string
```

[See demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OVRHxT/1).